# JSLint on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, jslint

I was using JSLint with VS 2015 due to a company policy. Now I have moved to VS2017 but seems there's no way to install the linter, so every time I have to write some javascript code, the tests on CI are very likely to fail.

Any hint?

Comment: I'm not able to say JSLint is available for Visual Studio 2017 yet..., however, it may be possible to check for JS errors by using the TypeScript engine provided with Visual Studio 2017. ([Wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio))

Comment: Would you be willing to use ESLint? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#eslint-improvements

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue. You have to install Visual Studio 2015 to install JSLint as Visual Studio 2017 is currently not supported with JSLint Dll.